# Add types for a form in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I try to add proper types for the form bellow:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

import "./index.css";

interface FormProps<T > {
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<T>,
  children: any
}

function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({defaultValues:{ firstName: 'hi'}});

  const Form = <T, >({children, onSubmit}: FormProps<T>) => {
  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{children}</form>
  }

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Form<{firstName: string}> onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder="Kotaro" />
        {errors?.firstName && <p>{errors.firstName.message}</p>}
      </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    </Form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I added types here: `<Form<{firstName: string}> onSubmit={onSubmit}>` and expect to have types inference for this  function: `const onSubmit = (data) => {`, but here TS require to add types for `data` - Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006), even i added rhis `<Form<{firstName: string}>`. 
 How to achieve the expected result? And why the inference is not working for `data`?
 demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-handlesubmit-ts-v7-forked-sd69oe?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 1):

I think it worth moving `Form` out of component scope and type it in a right way:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler, UseFormHandleSubmit } from "react-hook-form";

import "./index.css";

interface FormProps<T> {
  onSubmit: SubmitHandler<T>;
  children: any;
  handleSubmit: UseFormHandleSubmit<T>;
}

const Form = <T,>({ children, onSubmit, handleSubmit }: FormProps<T>) => {
  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{children}</form>;
};

type FormType={
  firstName: string
}
function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<FormType>({ defaultValues: { firstName: "hi" } });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormType> = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} handleSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder="Kotaro" />
        {errors?.firstName && <p>{errors.firstName.message}</p>}
      </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    </Form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: my target is to keep all the types related the hook inside Form component, so here: `const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormType> = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };` i don't have to use SubmitHandler. Could you help?

Comment: @Asking see [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKOy8W)

Comment: @c, i need to keep everything related to `const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<FormType>({ defaultValues: { firstName: "hi" } });` inside Form component. So all the types related the hook should be used only inside the form and deeper but not outside. Could you help?

Comment: could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74125404/cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided-using-lint-staged