# Typescript - infer function parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to get already typed function parameter in my code:

```
const Test = <T, >(data: {submit: (d: T) => void}) => {
    console.log(data)
}

const submit = (d) => {
    console.log(d, 'data');
};

const props = {submit}
Test<{myData: string}>(props);
```

Now `(d)` from

```
const submit = (d) => {
    console.log(d, 'data');
};
```

throw this message: `Parameter 'd' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)`, but i expect to get already typed parameter with `{myData: string}` without typing `d` one more time, because it get the  generic `T` from `Test` function. 
 Question: How to get the expected scenario? 
 demo: [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgU2jAvDAPHANDAfACgBMBDKYgLhgG8IBXAIwFsBLKSoyuASlVxgDcQzQgF8eKPlQCwAKBjyYoSCAA2CAHQqQAcyKliXWSNmylyOk1aoYRcZNkLF4CKo1bdhHAHISZL1wBuIyCZU2dYAAcAJxAIiGsaBhYoYxlEaHQqRgBPABF9Smgo5jBtEQJo2IhAoA)

Answer (score 1):

As `Test` method is generic, you must make your `submit` also generic:

```
const Test = <T, >(data: {submit: (d: T) => void}) => {
    console.log(data)
}

const submit = <T, >(d: T) => {
    console.log(d, 'data');
};

const props = {submit}
Test<{myData: string}>(props);
```

Alternatively, you can move your type to submit method

```
const submit = (d: {myData: string}) => {
    console.log(d, 'data');
};
const props = {submit}
Test(props);
```

---

Another case, if the `Test` method wouldn't be generic, you could extract the type for `submit` method as follows:

```
const Test = (data: {submit: (d: string) => void}) => {
    console.log(data)
}

const submit: Parameters<typeof Test>[0]['submit'] =  (d) => {
    console.log(d, 'data');
};

const props = {submit}
```

Comment: could you help with this please.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74014727/add-types-for-a-form-in-react-js

Comment: Sorry, I don't know React. But you can make your `onSubmit`  generic also generic, and you won't get the error.

Comment: but if i do it generic then i can not get the values from `data`. It does not infer the values/

Comment: Right, this is not possible. You can infer from type declaration, not usage. If you want to infer from `Test`, then it must be generic, as `Test` is generic.  `Test<{myData: string}>(props);` is just a usage, you can't get the `{myData: string}` type inferred in submit. Assume you have `Test<{other: number}>(props)` somewhere in code. Type analyzer can't get all the files, and extract all possible Types you use for generic method.

Comment: See my update, regarding moving your type declaration from `Test<{myData: string}>` into `submit` method.