# Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided using lint-staged

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I installed a fresh version of react with typescript on my local machine. Now i get these files:

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

```
App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  console.log('hello')
  const a: any = 10
  return (
    <div className="App">
      hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
package.json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:checktypes": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "yarn lint:checktypes"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Having these files and doing `git add .` and after that `yarn lint-staged` i get the next issue:

```
Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.
```

I tried a lot of potential solutions but without any success. 
 Question: Is there an issue with ReactJS or i have a problem in my code? 
 NOTE: interesting, when i do `yarn lint:checktypes` i don't get any error message.

Comment: try ` "jsx": "preserve"`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine, no updates, same issue

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine, may you help with this?

Comment: I can try, but minimum reproducible github repo